# Distinct values from DataFrame to Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get the distinct values of a single column of a `DataFrame` (called: `df`) into an Array that matches the data type of the column. This is what I've tried, but it does not work:

```
def distinctValues[T: ClassTag](column: String): Array[T] = {
      df.select(df(column)).distinct.map {
        case Row(s: T) => s
      }.collect
    }
```

The method is inside an implicit class, so calling `df.distinctValues("some_col")` gives me:

```
scala.MatchError: [ABCD] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve what I want that is also type safe?

I'm on Spark 1.4.1.

Comment: not sure why the pattern matching fails, but if you replace that map call with `map(_.getAs[T](column))` you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using pattern matching instead of the `getAs` method:

```
implicit final class DataFrameOps(val df: DataFrame) {
  def distinctValues[T: ClassTag](column: String): Array[T] = {
     df.select(column).distinct().map(_.getAs[T](column)).collect()
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val ageArray: Array[Int] = df.distinctValues("age")
or
val ageArray = df.distinctValues[Int]("age")
```

Comment: That gives `error: value class may not be a member of another class`.

Comment: You should remove `extends AnyVal` then, so it will work even if that final class is nested in another class. I've edited the example, so it will be more general.

Comment: When I look at the limitations (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), I don't see why this is a problem though. `DataFrame` is not a value class itself. There are no  nested traits/objects/classes, only defs, no specialized type parameters, it doesn't have a custom `equals` or `hashCode` function. If I place it inside an `object` it's member of a top-level statically accessible object. So what's the problem? I'm curious.

Comment: It should work (and works for me) if it's declared in an object. Have you checked if this final class is accessible from other files, for example using an import?

Comment: Hmm, I just wrapped it in `object SomeTest` and copy-pasted it in my Spark shell (1.4.1) and it gives me the error message. I checked the source for my version and it does not seem to `extend AnyVal`, so I'm not sure I understand the problem. https://github.com/apache/spark/releases/tag/v1.4.1

Comment: I have investigated this and there seems to be an issue with value classes in Spark shell, because in Scala shell they work like a charm. I guess that Spark shell wraps your statements/declarations in some generated class, and that way it disallows using value classes.

Comment: It could be the class `SparkILoop`, which creates an interpreter loop. Everything seems to be inside that class.

Comment: You're right, this might be the case. @Ian if you found my earlier answer helpful, feel free to making it the accepted one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.4.0, Spark has `dropDuplicates` method that implements distinct by sequence of columns (or by all columns, if none is specified):

```
//drop duplicates considering specified columns
val distinctDf = df.select($"column").dropDuplicates(Seq("column"))
//this should work too since df has one column after select
val distinctDf = df.select($"column").dropDuplicates()
//collect
def getValues[T](df: DataFrame, columnName: String) = {
  df.map(_.getAs[T](columnName)).collect()
}

getValues[String](distinctDf, "column")
```

Comment: Which is just an alias for `distinct`, so it does exactly the same. Moreover, I'm looking for a way to have different types handled and not hard-coding `String`. So, my question is really about going from a `DataFrame` of a single column to an `Array[T]` with `T` the type of the column in the `DataFrame`.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Yes, `distinct` is an alias for `dropDuplicates` version withoout parameters. `dropDuplicates`, as mentioned has another, more generic signature

Comment: Thanks! There is no way the type can be inferred? I mean: a `DataFrame` is a typed object, so that info should be available.

Comment: unlikely, because DataFrame is not strong typed - it does not have type parameters. That was the reason, why Databricks introduced [DataSet](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html) recently. So if you can upgrade you Spark instance to 1.6 - skip DataFrames and try DataSets instead.

Comment: That's not accurate - a DataFrame _can_ be matched using pattern matching (thanks to `Row.unapply` and the fact that `DataFrame.map` actually calls `RDD[Row].map`), it's just that a generic type (T in this case) can't be used in pattern matching this way. A version of the OP's matching expression using simpler generic container (e.g. List) doesn't work either. The workarounds are valid, but the root cause is different.